# get key of multi dimension array (PHP Language)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Hi I have a problem regarding multi-dimension array. I have a set of array looking like this

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "tree" => "0"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "tree" => "2"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "tree" => "0"
  ]
]
```

the array is from

```
dd($this->treeArray);
```

how do I want to get the array which the value is 0. Expected result/filter
For example:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "tree" => "0"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "tree" => "0"
  ]
]

or 

array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "tree" => "2"
  ]
]
```

if changing the index is impossible, its ok..
Thank you

Comment: oh yeah, sorry did not mention it, It's PHP

Comment: `foreach($this->fruitArray as $aa) foreach ($aa as $n => $v) if ($v == "0") echo "$n\n";` (when your question was asking about getting the names for value "0" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Laravel, you could use array helper [such as this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-where)

You can use like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$newTreeArray = Arr::where($this->treeArray, function ($tree) => $tree['tree'] === "0");
```

Comment: I did not know of this, but it works. Thank you... I think I remember the structure, quite similar to Str:: structure. I think I have to read Laravel docs over and over again. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

do you want in_array()?

```
$arraysContainingZero=[];
foreach($this->treeArray as $wutkey => $wut){
    if(in_array("0", $wut, true)){
        $arraysContainingZero[$wutkey] = $wut;
    }
}
var_dump($arraysContainingZero);
```

Comment: this is great, I had tried using in_array before but failed miserable.. I forgot to use $arraysContainingZero[$wutkey] = $wut; .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of build in function in PHP that is useful for operating on an array. You can see the full list here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

One of the function is called array_filter (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). The function iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback function. If the callback function returns true, the current value from array is returned into the result array.

So in your case, you want to call the array_filter with a callback that return true if the value is 0. Example:

```
$input = [
        [ 'tree' => 1 ],
        [ 'tree' => 0 ],
        [ 'tree' => 0 ],
    ];
    
$output = array_filter($input, function($arr) {
    return $arr['tree'] === 0;
});
var_dump($output);

// result 
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["tree"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["tree"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```